# Rotate arrow without using Unity3d physics engine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I have this code that simulates the movement of a projectile without using the unity physics engine

```
IEnumerator LaunchProjectile(int angle, float speed)
{

    // Move projectile to the position of throwing object + add some offset if needed.
    Projectile.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0f, 0);
    Projectile.rotation = transform.root.rotation;
    Debug.Log(transform.root.eulerAngles);

    // Calculate distance to target
    float target_Distance = speed * (Mathf.Sin(2 * firingAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad) / gravity);

    // Extract the X  Y componenent of the velocity
    float Vx = Mathf.Sqrt(speed) * Mathf.Cos(firingAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
    float Vy = Mathf.Sqrt(speed) * Mathf.Sin(firingAngle * Mathf.Deg2Rad); 

    // Calculate flight time.
    float flightDuration = target_Distance / Vx;

    this.arrowSimulationScript = Projectile.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<ArrowSimulation>();

    float elapse_time = 0;

    while (!arrowSimulationScript.Collided())
    {
        Projectile.Translate(0, (Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime, Vx * Time.deltaTime);

        Projectile.LookAt(Projectile.position - new Vector3(0,  (Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime, Vx * Time.deltaTime));

        arrowSimulationScript.Velocity = new Vector3(0, (Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime, Vx * Time.deltaTime).magnitude;

        elapse_time += Time.deltaTime;

        yield return null;
    }
}
```

The arrow is fired in the direction of the object which has this script attached. To make the arrow rotate I use this line of code:

```
Projectile.LookAt(Projectile.position - new Vector3(0,  (Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime, Vx * Time.deltaTime));
```

The arrow moves towards the right direction but with the tip facing the z axis direction, instead of the direction of the bow.
Here is a video of the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyK6DXxTw_E

If I comment out that line of code the arrow fly with the tip facing the direction of the bow, but it doesn't rotate.

Comment: Even though this isn't directly about Unity3D and more general maths. This question may do better over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ due to its physics maths content.

Comment: Thx, posted there too.

Comment: its facing z because x is zero. i cant really do the mental math but shouldn't x be ((Vx - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime)  and z should be the average of Vx and Vy.

Comment: @Thouartamazing something like that: `LookAt(Projectile.position - new Vector3(Vx * Time.deltaTime,  
                                                                               (Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime, 
                                                                               ( ((Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime) + (Vx * Time.deltaTime) ) / 2));`  It doesn't work :(

Comment: first remove the deltatimes, those dont make a difference, and unnecesarily complicate your equation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
while (!arrowSimulationScript.Collided())
{
    Vector3 delta = new Vector3(0, (Vy - (gravity * elapse_time)) * Time.deltaTime, Vx * Time.deltaTime);
    Vector3 newPos = Projectile.position + delta;
    Vector3 offset = (newPos - Projectile.position);
    Vector3 magnitude = offset.magnitude;
    Vector3 newDir = offset.normalized;

    Projectile.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir, Vector3.Cross(newDir, Projectile.right)));

    arrowSimulationScript.Velocity = magnitude;

    elapse_time += Time.deltaTime;
    Projectile.position = newPos;

    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: I get a compile error: `Projectile.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation((newPos - Projectile.position).normalized, Vector3.Dot(Projectile.right, newDir));` LookRotation, takes two Vector3 objects as arguments, the second one is a float.

Comment: Sorry i meant to make a `Cross` product, not `Dot` product

Comment: Thank you, but it works like the old code, same effect as you can see in the video